# PHP dynamically change filename

Tags: php, jquery, slideshow

I was able to get some help earlier today, but I didn't have everything from the original script for it to work. Basically I have a list of image file names in a .txt file. They each load in a slideshow, and change with the pagination on the page.

What I would like to do, is if I have a file that has a .mov extension, for example, the php script will load a movie player instead.

Here is the original slideshow script

```
<div id='jessslide'>
  <?php
  echo"
<div id='slider-wrapper'>
<div id='slider' class='nivoSlider'>";
  $photos = file("work.txt");
  foreach ($photos as $image) {
    $item = explode("|", $image);
    if ($item[0] == $fields[0]) {
      $photo = trim($item[1]);
      echo"<img src='images/work/$photo' alt='' />\n";
    }
  }
  echo"
</div></div>"
  ?>
</div>
```

And here is my bad attempt at trying to make this work...

```
<div id='jessslide'>
  <?php
  $photos = file("work.txt");
  $img = array('jpg', 'png', 'gif');
  $vid = array('swf', 'mp4', 'mov', 'mpg', 'flv');
  foreach ($photos as $image) {
  $item = explode("|", $image);
  if ($item[0] == $fields[0]) {
  $photo = trim($item[1]);
  $ext = explode(".", $image);

  if (in_array($ext[1], $img)) 
  {
  echo "<div id='slider-wrapper'><div id='slider' class='nivoSlider'><img src='images/work/$photo' alt='' /> </div></div>";  
   } 
   elseif (in_array($ext[1], $vid)) 
   {
   echo "<iframe src='$photo' width='800' height='450' frameborder='0' webkitAllowFullScreen allowFullScreen></iframe>";
   }
   }
   }
   ?>
   </div>
```

I would really appreciate if someone could help me out to finally bring this script to life! :)

Comment: Where does the `$fields` array get defined? I'm trying to see what that if statement does... Or can we assume that this portion of the script is accurate and working?

Comment: Also, it will help you and anyone you have look at your code if you use consistent indenting every time you open a curly brace.

Comment: Final note: What behavior are you currently seeing from the script, as written now? Is it outputting anything from the innermost if?

Comment: Sorry about the bad indenting. The fields array bit is accurate and works :)

Comment: With the modified script, the page doesn't show the slideshow (or movie player). Everything else that isn't a part of that php script shows up fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely problem I see is the possibility that the assignment to `$ext` should be tied to `$item` or `$photo` instead of `$image`. If that solves it, then great. Otherwise, read below for a more complete analysis and some suggestions for steps to debug until you narrow in on the cause of the problem.

---

Assuming all of the data is accurate, the script you've written looks like it should work. I've reformatted it here to conduct some analysis:

```
<div id='jessslide'>
<?php
$photos=file("work.txt");
$img = array('jpg', 'png', 'gif');
$vid = array('swf', 'mp4', 'mov', 'mpg', 'flv');
foreach($photos as $image){
  $item=explode("|",$image);
  if($item[0]==$fields[0]){
    $photo=trim($item[1]);
    $ext = explode(".", $image);

    if(in_array($ext[1], $img))
    { echo "<div id='slider-wrapper'><div id='slider' class='nivoSlider'><img src='images/work/$photo' alt='' /> </div></div>"; }
    elseif(in_array($ext[1], $vid))
    { echo "<iframe src='$photo' width='800' height='450' frameborder='0'     webkitAllowFullScreen allowFullScreen></iframe>"; }
  }
}
?>
</div>
```

There are three major places in this script for problems to occur that would cause nothing to be output.

The first is in the `foreach()` loop. If the `$photos` array has nothing in it, you would skip the entire block of code. You can test for this condition by adding a `print_r($photos);` before the `foreach()` and then as the first line in the body of the `foreach()` add `echo $image." ";` to verify that all the files are listed as you expect. If that looks correct, remove that debugging code and move on.

The 2nd potential for problems is if the `$item[0]` is not equal to `$fields[0]`. To test this, add `echo 0;` as the first line inside `if($item[0]==$fields[0])`. If you see zeros as expected when the script is run, then you can remove this debugging code and move on.

The 3rd potential for problems is pull/examination of the extension. One likely candidate for problems here is if the assignment to `$ext` should be tied to `$item` or `$photo` instead of `$image` but there are definitely other possible issues. To test this, add `echo $image." ".$ext[1]."\n"; print_r($img); print_r($vid);` before the `if(in_array($ext[1], $img))`. Then add a temporary else clause with the body of `echo 3;` as well. Verify that th

Once you figure out which condition in the code is causing problems, you will be well on the way toward solving it. My guess is that you'll get through the tests and either find an obvious mistake in one of the early sections that we are assuming works right, or you will end up with 3 being printed out a lot. In the later case, one possible issue could come from lower/upper-case differences, which could be solved via changing the `$item` assignment to `$item=strtolower(explode("|", $image);`

Comment: Thank you soooo much!! I went through all of it, and it turned out to be what you suggested at the start! $ext needed to be assigned to $photo instead of image... duh! ><;; Thank you again! You've made my day haha! :D

Comment: It's good that you read through all of it. You can do similar things to debug any script :)