# Dynamically change the downloaded filename

Tags: php, download

How do I dynamically change the downloaded filename using php? This excel sheet was converted from an HTML table using Javascript. Now I want to dynamically change the filename each time it is downloaded. I'm using an `input` type button as the download button.

---

> **Editorial Note:**
>   Based on comments, this question may be reworded as follows.

I want people to be able to download an Excel Sheet from the server. How do I force a file download and set the name of the file based on the month? When I download the file it shows “download.xls”

*`No code provided`*

See comments:

- [keep name same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17876387/dynamically-change-the-downloaded-filename/17876679#comment26103445_17876387)
- [shows download.xls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17876387/dynamically-change-the-downloaded-filename/17876679#comment26103930_17876679)
- [based on month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17876387/dynamically-change-the-downloaded-filename/17876679#comment26103663_17876679)
- [server-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17876387/dynamically-change-the-downloaded-filename/17876679#comment26106970_17876679)

Comment: And what code do you use to download the file?

Comment: Also, do you want to change the name of the file on the server or keep the name of the file on the server the same but change the name of the downloaded file?

Comment: ya i would like to keep the name of the file on the server the same

Comment: Flagged as "unclear what you're asking"

Comment: @Herbert It seems that — [according to his latest comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17876387/dynamically-change-the-downloaded-filename/17876679#comment26106970_17876679) — there were enough good hints for him to find an answer that fits his needs. Personally, I wish I could have flagged this with an *“I'm confused by the question but I'm sure I will get over it… somewhere in the future.”*. ;)

Comment: @e-sushi: I second that.

Comment: @rahul Any chance to get an *"accept"* on one of the answers? You just have to click the checkmark of the answer you think fits your question best.

Answer (score 2):

You write

> This excel sheet was converted from an HTML table using Javascript.

That would mean the HTML table is available as EXCEL file at the client's side already.

If that is the case, there is no reason to push the converted EXCEL file from the client back to the server, just so the client can download it from the server again. That wouldn't make sense and waste bandwidth on a useless loop.

In other words: when the EXCEL file already resides in the client's Javascript memory, all you need to do is to store your (Javascript converted) EXCEL file to a filename based on something like Javascript's `Math.random()`. As for an easy approach to file saving, things like HTML5's file-saving capabilities (as one of many ways to do it) may become your best friends.

Think about it: if you're sitting on your sofa at home, you don't drive to work just to be able to drive back home and fetch a beer from the fridge in your home's kitchen, do you? Right, you just stay at home and walk into the kitchen to grab that beer. ;)

Same here: if you convert it client-side and the client has the file in his computer's memory, let him save that onto his disks. Don't force him to upload the whole file just so he can download it… as said: Javascript's `Math.random()` enables you to produce a random number which you can use to create random filenames.

**EDIT**

Based on [OP's question in comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17876387/dynamically-change-the-downloaded-filename/17876679#comment26103663_17876679):

> but how to save these downloaded files with a dynamic file name according to the month.

To create a filename based on the month, you would use Javascript's Date like this:

```
var now = new Date(); 
var month = now.getMonth();
```

And if you're looking for hints on how to store your file client-side, you might want to dive into:

- [Saving generated files on the client-side](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Saving-generated-files-on-the-client-side)

If you want to handle it server-side and push the file towards the client using PHP with your own filename based upon the `year-month-day`, you could go like this:

```
<?php
$realname = './data.xls';
if (file_exists($realname )) 
{
    $randname = 'YourExcelFilename'.gmdate('Y-m-d').'.xls';
    header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); 
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$randname);
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($realname));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
}
exit();
?>
```

<sup>(**EDIT 2**: Corrected the above example by removing 2 unnecessary headers [thanks to a comment by @Herbert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17876387/dynamically-change-the-downloaded-filename/17876679#comment26108918_17876679))</sup>

If you want more alternative solutions, you might want to check the answers to [the two questions I linked in my first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17876387/dynamically-change-the-downloaded-filename/17876679#comment26103055_17876387) since your question is a *potential duplicate* of those questions

- ["PHP dynamically change filename"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7932721/2432317)
- ["PHP and Download Excel Sheet"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14396199/2432317).

Comment: but how to save these downloaded files with a dynamic file name according to the month.

Comment: when i download the file it shows download.xls

Comment: @rahul See my **EDIT**. If your file now says `download.xls`, you will simply have to rename it using the `month` var you see in my EDIT's example.

Comment: no i have downloaded excel file properly, but i can't change the filename of that downloaded file according to the month.

Comment: @rahul You might want to check the information and link I provided (based on your question and comments) and try to learn from it by coding your project yourself. Don't expect me (or anyone else) to write your project for you. It's not going to happen.

Comment: the answer was putting these two codes in the download page where the table was header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$flname");, but more thing no button is required, a link with that download page reference is only required.

Comment: @rahul Well, that's server-side then. Guess posting some of your code would have helped finding the solution a bit quicker. ;) Anyway, I'm glad you found a solution that fits your needs…  greets!

Comment: Apparently OP didn't read my answer. :P Anyway, according to [this guy](http://www.richnetapps.com/the-right-way-to-handle-file-downloads-in-php/) "Content-Description" and "Content-Transfer-Encoding" doesn't exist in HTTP.

Comment: @Herbert OP confused me for the rest of the day. I've quit hoping to understand him. Guess we can't expect any *accept* either. ;) | **Re: headers**: Hmmm… *php.net* uses them in ["Example #1 Forcing a download using readfile()"](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php), but checking that myself it turns out you and *"that guy"* are correct. Those are [MIME](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2045.txt), not [HTTP/1.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) headers. Geez — must be the fact that I never serve files like that. My bad… I'll edit my answer accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the headers are an IE5 mac thing or something. I don't know. :P I edited the question to reflect the new information strewn throughout the comments. When I first read it, I figured the javascript thing was as irrelevant as the `<input>` button. Your answer deserves the accept as it goes into more detail than mine.

Answer (score 2):

Apply the generated file name to the Content-Disposition header.

```php
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$random_filename\"");
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
readfile($actual_filename);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can rename a file on the server with PHP's rename function http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php